# Why does pointer to malloc'd area fail unless copied?

Tags: c, malloc

I have a pointer to a struct. I call a routine that determines whether I need this struct and allocates space for it using malloc, returning the pointer to that area or zero if unused.

```
struct node *node_p;
node_p = need_this();
```

This works and I can properly access all the elements of the struct. One of the elements of struct node is *next which points to the next node struct and a pointer to a string but it's returning a pointer to a string that doesn't even exist in this routine.

```
node_p=find_string(node_p->next,"string");
```

However, this does return a pointer in the struct to the correct string.

```
struct node *node_p, *node_copy;
node_copy=find_string(node_p->next,"string");
```

The only difference is using a second pointer instead of the original. Am I doing something wrong here or must it be deeper into the called function? The problem with blaming the called function is I use it in multiple places for months without issue, however the other calls only look for the string and never go to 'next'.

> **EDIT:** Further debugging has shown the problem actually lies with the pointer being passed to find_string and not the returned pointer. That changes the question and the problem so I need to open another question.

Comment: This sounds confusing. `find_string` should return a `struct node *`, but you're talking about returning a pointer to a string. Maybe you should show us `find_string`, the problem seems to be inside this.

Comment: ... it should be the same... how do you check if it is right or wrong? do you access `node_p` or `node_copy` in the second sample? the only difference is that `node_p` is not trashed...

Comment: @Secure - yes, find_string does return a pointer to the node struct which contains a pointer to a string.

@ShinTakezou - I check this by printing node_p->string and node_copy->string. The second prints the correct string. The first prints a string unrelated to this routine but used in another module altogether.

Comment: Maybe a buffer/stack overflow inside find_string that happens to overwrite node_p in the caller? Check node_p when assigning to node_copy, it should remain unchanged. What happens when you write `struct node *node_copy, *node_p;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this snippet:

```
struct node *node_p, *node_copy;
node_copy=find_string(node_p->next,"string");
```

you dereference `node_p` when it is not yet initialized (doesn't point to a legally allocated memory block). That's undefined behavior. You should set `node_p` to a legally allocated memory block of appropriate size first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory explicitly for every struct, i.e. allocate a new struct and set next pointer to point to it.
Pointers in C prior to initialization point to random place and you never should dereference them. Safe policy would be to init them to be NULLs.